# cant get cifs to mount network drive during boot using fstab

Tags: linux, cifs

Im trying to get a network share to mount on startup using cifs. I can get the share to mount after linux boots, but for some reason I cant get it to work when editing the `/etc/fstab` file.

Here's the line that works after the system boots

`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=user,password=password //mycloud/drive//media/drive`

Here's the line in the fstab file

`//mycloud/drive /media/drive  cifs username=user,password=password,_netdev`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that `cifs` doesn't use `_netdev` so I found this post https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=124673 which uses `x-systemd.automount` instead